# Can't install from Ubuntu Software Center in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, software-sources

I am a new user to Ubuntu, presently using Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit. I can't install any software from the Ubuntu Software Center. I am getting errors such as: `failed to download repository information`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update
```

If that doesn't help, try changing the download server as show in the image below.

[image]